# JS - access the object value by key but occur the message [TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following data

```
indexMap = {"A": 0, "B": 1};
self.ctx.chart.data.datasets = [
    {
        "label" : "A",
        "data" : [0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    {
        "label" : "B",
        "data" : [0,0,0,0,0]
    },
]
```

When I want to access data array of the first object of the datasets array,
I write the code below :

```
var idx = indexMap["A"];
var data = self.ctx.chart.data.datasets[idx].data; // <--- error occur [TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]
```

But the error occurs, that says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

But the self.ctx.chart.data.datasets[idx] can print the value like below:

```
{
    "label" : "A",
    "data" : [0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

the variable self.ctx.chart.data.datasets[idx] really has the key 'data'

How do I fix it?
BTW, when I using the code below is no problem, why?

```
var idx = 0;
var data = self.ctx.chart.data.datasets[idx].data; // <--- this is ok!!! why!!!!
```

Comment: See weather you are getting 0 for indexMap["A"]

Comment: As said by @YerrapotuManojKiran, I'd log the value of `indexMap["A"]` in the scope you are accessing it in. This error makes me suspect that `indexMap` is not in scope.

Comment: Are either of the objects populated asynchronously?

Comment: Using a “map” to resolve a _value_ makes **no** difference to the _value_ used later, assuming it is the same _value_. Hence, given the code, it must be a different _value_. (And likely hypotheses are the “map” usage is incorrect or the problem is misrepresented.)

Comment: @adiga if objects populated asynchronously, the error will occur ? sorry i'm not good at this, thx

Comment: Maybe I found the answer.  If you want to access the object value in the array, you need to check the current object is null or not then you can get the object value by key.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine if the data provided are correct

```
 let indexMap = {"A": 0, "B": 1};
    
    this.ctx = [
        {
            "label" : "A",
            "data" : [0,0,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            "label" : "B",
            "data" : [0,0,0,0,0]
        },
    ];
    
    let id = indexMap["A"];
    console.log((id))
    
     this.result = this.ctx[id].data;
```

[CheckThis](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ca6sm)

Comment: If it works as it is, please flag it as not reproducible instead of answering.(The question was closed but reopened for some reason).  The question has no future value to the site. If the question has upvoted answers, OP or [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) can't delete it and it sticks around forever.

Comment: @adiga I have assigned the input to one variable rather he mentioned like self.ctx.chart.data.datasets. Then after only its works. So it may related to the input. So he need check that part only..